# Gradle Task dependsOn multiple parameters

Tags: android, gradle

I have 3 gradle tasks:first,second,third.

```
task first {
    doLast {
        println "+++++first+++++"
    }
}
task second {
    doLast {
        println "+++++second+++++"
    }
}

task third(dependsOn :[second,first]) {
    doLast {
        println "+++++third+++++"
    }
}
```

execute 'gradle third' in cmd,the result is

```
E:\android\GradleTest>gradle third

> Task :app:first
+++++first+++++

> Task :app:second
+++++second+++++

> Task :app:third
+++++third+++++
```

dependsOn task order is [second,first],But why execute task order is "+++++first+++++" " +++++second+++++"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When declaring [Task Dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:task_dependencies) using `dependsOn` like that you're not specifying an order; you're just saying `third` depends on both `one` and `two`.  Gradle can then look at the dependency graph of all the tasks in the build and decide in which order to run them all.

If you also have a dependency between `one` and `two` you should declare it explicitly.

You can do more subtle things with [task ordering](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:ordering_tasks) using `mustRunAfter` and `shouldRunAfter` but these are intendend for special cases only, and are rarely what you want. Just focus on the dependencies and let Gradle worry about the ordering.

Comment: Thank  you.This is a good answer to the question.